# Mongoengine type object 'unicode' has no attribute '_meta'

Tags: python, django, mongoengine

The following its a small portion of the code I have on my django model's files:

```
class Component(Document):
    id = IntField(primary_key=True)

class GenericComponent(Document):
    id = IntField(primary_key=True)

class Block(Document):
    components = GenericReferenceField() # can be Component or GenericComponent

# This line gives the error:
component_ids = request.POST.getlist('components')
Block.objects.filter(components__in=component_ids)
```

So I made several other changes on my models and couldn't find why this issue was happening everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

`GenericReferenceField` expects an object with meta attribute which has the Document's Name instead of a `unicode` so this solved everything:

```
component_ids = GenericComponent.objects.filter(
        id__in=request.POST.getlist('components'))
Block.objects.filter(components__in=component_ids)
```

It searches for a list of objects with `_meta` attribute and filters correctly for the right `Reference`.